# How to pass a decimal value when making a post request in django?

Tags: json, python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework, decimal

I am trying to make a post request to a third party application along with some data and the data also have a decimal value up to two points, which I am getting from database (order.amount) but after making the request getting error saying data is not serializable to json then i passed it as '"%s"' % round(order.amount,2) then also getting error post data is empty.Looking for suggestion to solve this problem.

```
    request = Transfer.request_transfer(beneId=beneficiary_id, amount=round((order.amount),2) 
    transferId=transfer_identifier,remarks="Test transfer")

    getting error: decimal is not json serializable

    print('"%s"' % round((order.amount),2) #"5000.23"
    
    request = Transfer.request_transfer(beneId=beneficiary_id, amount='"%s"' % round((order.amount),2) transferId=transfer_identifier,remarks="Test transfer")
    
    getting error : PreconditionFailedError: Reason = Post data is empty or not a valid JSON:: response = {"status": "ERROR", "subCode": "412", "message": "Post data is empty or not a valid JSON"}
    
    
    but when hardcoding amount then it is working
    request = Transfer.request_transfer(beneId=beneficiary_id, amount= "5000.23" transferId=transfer_identifier,remarks="Test transfer")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pay attention to this line,

```py
print('"%s"' % round((order.amount),2) #"5000.23"
```

I guess you miss one thing: you're formatting your decimal value, but you do this with quotes, so your variable `amount` will contain `"5000.23"` string instead of `5000.23`.

So, look:

```py
request = Transfer.request_transfer(beneId=beneficiary_id, amount='"%s"' % round((order.amount),2) transferId=transfer_identifier,remarks="Test transfer")
```

you have `amount='"5000.23"'` and these quotes get in the way of serialization.

To fix it, just remove the additional quotes:

```py
print('%s' % round((order.amount),2) # '5000.23'

request = Transfer.request_transfer(beneId=beneficiary_id, amount='%s' % round((order.amount),2) transferId=transfer_identifier,remarks="Test transfer")
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @FedorIvanov it worked. Its was such a smell mistake and I was stuck on this since yesterday.

Answer (score 0):

The `round` function according to [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#round):

> The return value is an integer if *ndigits* is omitted or `None`.
> Otherwise the return value has the same type as *number*.

Hence `round` when passed a `Decimal` and `ndigits` will return a `Decimal`, hence passing `amount=round((order.amount),2)` will not do what you assume it does (converting to `float` or  `int`). Also converting `Decimal` to `float` implies a loss of precision which we **don't** want (The whole reason we would be using `Decimal`). To pass a `Decimal` value one would simply pass it as a ***string*** (Which of course implies we would need to perform some type casting at the client side if we want to perform arithmetic using it):

```
request = Transfer.request_transfer(
    beneId=beneficiary_id,
    amount=str(order.amount),
    transferId=transfer_identifier,
    remarks="Test transfer"
)
```

Comment: Thank you for the response @AbdulAzizBarkat..I used round function because 3rd party application has mentioned that they accept amount up to two decimal point so if I do str(order.amount) then it becomes a string but value is 50000.1235 which is not as per the 3rd party app instruction

Comment: @AmitYadav Then use `str(round(order.amount, 2))`

Comment: I tried this too but was getting the same error.  Now it is resolved I was writing ' "%s" ' % round((order.amount),2) instead of '%s' % round((order.amount),2).though thanks a lot for the suggestions.